# WSWS3499W: How to make WAS understand the HTTP 302 response from a web service?

Tags: java, web-services, websphere, load-balancing, http-status-code-302

We have a Java application running on WebSphere Application Server (hereinafter - "Client"), which makes web service calls to another application distributed across two data centers with a load balancer on top of it.

Load balancer works the following way:

1. you hit the load balancer URL
2. it gives you a HTTP 302 response with a new URL (one of the data centers)
3. Client application talks directly to a web service application in one of the data centers

For example:

```
    > curl -i -s -k https://stealthwsort-1810.*.*/StealthWS/StealthServices
    HTTP/1.0 302 Found
    Location: https://stealthwsort-1810-vip.*.*:5443/StealthWS/StealthServices
    Content-Type: text/html
    Expires: Mon, 1 Jan 2001 00:00:00 GMT
    Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
    Pragma: no-cache
    Server: BigIP
    Connection: Keep-Alive
    Content-Length: 0
```

For some reason our Client application does not understand the HTTP 302 response  from the load balancer and throws WSWS3514E and WSWS3499W errors in logs:

```
    [3/23/16 9:12:36:066 GMT] 00000029 HttpOutboundC E   WSWS3514E: No HTTP response body is available from the connection for: https://stealthwsort-1810.apaas-np.*.*/StealthWS/StealthServices
    [3/23/16 9:12:36:068 GMT] 00000029 SystemOut     O esEligibilityWs(ERROR)=Unable to process the Stealth Status request at site : https://stealthwsort-1810.apaas-np.*.*/StealthWS/StealthServices : Error : WSWS3499W: Redirected new location: https://stealthwsort-1810.apaas-np.*.*/StealthWS/StealthServices
        at bundles.workflow.classes.TaskWrapper.execute(TaskWrapper.java:581)
        at bundles.workflow.classes.ProcessController.processTask(Unknown Source)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:831)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1661)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1602)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:113)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain._doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:80)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:908)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:939)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:507)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:181)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppRequestDispatcher.forward(WebAppRequestDispatcher.java:374)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.CacheServletWrapper.handleRequest(CacheServletWrapper.java:91)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:878)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1592)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:191)
        at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:453)
        at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:515)
        at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:306)
        at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpICLReadCallback.complete(HttpICLReadCallback.java:84)
        at com.ibm.ws.ssl.channel.impl.SSLReadServiceContext$SSLReadCompletedCallback.complete(SSLReadServiceContext.java:1819)
        at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:175)
        at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
        at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture$1.run(AsyncChannelFuture.java:205)
        at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1660)
```

IBM website suggests:

> You may want to check the product documentation for details about how to accept the automatic redirection to the new location.

But I can't find any specific manual in this matter.

Please point me into right direction. I am ready to provide additional details if required.

Thanks,
Yevgen

Answer (score 2):

To get started, you need to configure some additional HTTP transport Properties for the JVM:

1. Open the administrative console.

   Click Servers > Application Servers > server > Java and Process Management > Process Definition > Java Virtual Machine > Custom Properties.
2. Optional: If the property is not listed, create a new property name.
3. Enter the name and value.
4. Optional: Accept the redirection of the HTTP request to a different URI in HTTPS.

   A redirection of the HTTP request to a different URI in HTTPS can occur if the transport guarantee of CONFIDENTIAL or INTEGRAL is configured in the application. To accept the redirection, you can do either of the following tasks:

   - Set the `com.ibm.ws.webservices.HttpRedirectEnabled` Java system property to true.
   - Programmatically set the `com.ibm.wsspi.webservices.Constants.HTTP_REDIRECT_ENABLED` property to a java.lang.Boolean object in the Stub or Call object before invoking the service. For example, use any of the following `java.lang.Boolean` values to set the property to true:

     - Boolean.TRUE
     - new Boolean(true)
     - new Boolean("true")

As requested, the Product Documentation can be found on the following link:
http://www14.software.ibm.com/webapp/wsbroker/redirect?version=phil&product=was-base-iseries&topic=twbs_configaddhttppropertiesadmin